# Insert selected text from one file into multiple files -python

Tags: python, file

I have file(lets call it file_A) from which I extract 5 lines (like so)

```
 pppppppp
 qqqqqqqq
 rrrrrrrr
 ssssssss
 tttttttt
```

Now I want to insert these five lines at the beginning of 10 other files (lets call them 1..10).

I want to open file_A (one with the 5 lines) then open one by one the 10 files and insert these lines at the beginning of these files.

Right now I do the following:

1) open file_A, extract first of the five lines (pppppppp) write to new file
2) then the second line….so one.
3) open file 1 and copy all lines and then write out to new file opened in step 1
4) close all files…..repeat

So I end up with 10 new files while I would rather store the 5 lines extracted into the existing file and also avoid opening and closing file_A 10times !

What tool can I use to store the 5 lines in memory while doing this without distorting them?

Thank you

Comment: Just `.read` the whole file as a string and hold it in memory.

Comment: Or if you want to change their order around store them in a list. Each line as a different item of the list.

Comment: The problem is the five lines I want are in the middle of that file (file_A), so I don't want to read again and again to find those 5 lines.

Comment: Then `.readlines` to get a list and slice the lines you want out of it `lines = lines[x:x+5]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe or use `list(islice(fileobj, start, start+5))` (remembering to take 1 from start if counting lines from 1)

Comment: @jonrsharpe so you don't have to read the entire file to slice it (eg, if it's a 20 million line file, and you want 5 lines from line 10k... islice will skip the preceeding, the list will accumulate the 5 lines - then the file doesn't need to be read any further)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put files in a list, and iterate over the list:

```
    file_list = ["foo.txt","bar.txt"...]
    with open("file_A.txt","r+") as f: # open once
        # extract lines
        extracted = [] # put data here
        for f in file_list:
            with open(f, "r+") as out:
                lines = out.readlines()
                lines[0:0] = extracted # add data at start 
                out.seek(0)
                out.write("".join(lines)) # write new data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need the data re-written in place, but if not, you can use (untested):

```
from itertools import islice, chain

with open('filea.txt') as fin:
    first5 = list(islice(fin, 5)) # or whatever criteria to get the 5

for filename in ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']: #etc
    with open(filename) as fin, open(filename + '.out') as fout:
        fout.writelines(chain(first5, fin))
```